# Why can't I print the user input data in NASM assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to verify the length of user input in this example (NASM):

```
section .bss
    user_input resb 10

section .text
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 3 ;sys_read
    mov ebx, 0 ;stdin
    mov ecx, user_input
    mov edx, 10
    int 80h

    cmp eax, 10
    jg overflow
    jmp done 
overflow:
    .
    .
    .
done:
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

Since your buffer is 10 bytes and you put the length into edx, the return can never be greater than 10 and you jump to label `done:` and exit.

There's nothing in the code you've shown that prints anything out.

Comment: But if i digit more than 10 characters (with '\0'), it is accepted by the program... and i want to avoid this. How can i do this??

Comment: `cmp byte [ecx + eax - 1], 10]` - if the linefeed is in your buffer, there's been no overflow. If not, keep reading into a dummy buffer until the linefeed shows up. There's no '\0' involved (unless you overwrite the linefeed). Print it with sys_write, of course (which prints `edx` bytes - does not stop on '\0' or '\n').